# Pass a Mediaplayer in an other Activity

Tags: android, audio, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I have a Mediaplayer mpFond, started in my first activity. If I press the HOME, the mediaplayer is stopped, and if i press "PLAY" to go in my other activity, the sound continu (that's good). When I press the Home button in my first activity (where I started the mediaplayer), it's ok, my sound stop, but if **I press the Home button in the other activity, it does not** (and that's my problem).
So I just **want to know if I can pass the Mediaplayer in the other activity** to stop it when I press the Home button (without using Services, i'm new, so ...)

I just use that to stop the sound when I press the Home button :

```
  @Override
public void onPause()
{
   super.onPause();
   if(this.isFinishing()){
   mpFond.stop();
   }

}

@Override
public void onStop(){
   super.onStop();
  if(this.isFinishing()){
    mpFond.stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to be honest, also if you are a beginner it is more simple to start and stop a service than make strange things to link a media player object in different activity. Please check a very basic sample: https://github.com/orlando-antonino/WearAudioPlayer

Comment: But, i just want to start 1 sound in the entire app, without a sound manager, ...  so i do not know how to use Services in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, *there is no way you can pass the MediaPlayer object to another activity through intent*. Maybe it is because activity only passes Parcelable or Serializable objects. **But I just discovered another way**. To pass MediaPlayer to another activity you need to 
1- create the MediaPlayer inside your application object.
2- Access the MediaPlayer  from whatever activity you want and bind it over again to it.